# How to get the missing brick of the proof $A \circ P_\sigma = P_\sigma \circ A$ using permutations?

Tags: real-analysis, permutations, proof-explanation, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

I'm currently learning Exterior Algebra  to get a proof of Stoke's Theorem. Unfortunately, I don't understand the proof of a certain statement.
Before that I show you the proof, I have to introduce you some to some definition.

---

By knowing that $\alpha \in L^r(E,E)$, and $\epsilon(\sigma)$ is the signature of the corresponding permutation.
$$Permutation \space Operator:P_\sigma (\alpha)(v_1,\ldots, v_r):= \alpha (v_{\sigma(1)},\ldots, v_{\sigma(r)})$$
$$Antisymmetric \space Operator:A(\alpha)(v_1,\ldots, v_r):=\frac{1}{r!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_r}\epsilon(\sigma)P_\sigma(\alpha)(v_1,\ldots, v_r)$$

---

We want to prove this statement.
$$(A \circ P_\sigma) (\alpha) (v_1,\ldots, v_r)=(P_\sigma \circ A)(\alpha) (v_1,\ldots, v_r)=\epsilon(\sigma)A(\alpha) (v_1,\ldots, v_r)$$
Here is the demonstration written in a compact form.
$$(P_\sigma \circ r!A) (\alpha)=\color{red}{\sum_{\tau \in S_r} \epsilon(\tau)P_\sigma \circ P_\tau (\alpha)=\sum_{\tau \in S_r} \epsilon(\sigma^{-1}\tau)P_\tau (\alpha)}=\sum_{\tau \in S_r} \epsilon(\sigma^{-1})\epsilon(\tau)P_\tau(\alpha)=\epsilon(\sigma)\sum_{\tau \in S_r}\epsilon(\tau)P_\tau(\alpha)=\epsilon(\sigma)r!A (\alpha)$$

---

The only thing that I don't understand is where the equality colored in red comes from. I would be really glad to get an easy answer, such that someone like me who doesn't have some solid knowledge in group theory can understand it.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Comment: Notice that $P_{\sigma} \circ P_{\tau} (\alpha) = P_{\sigma \circ \tau} (\alpha)$. 

Now since you are summing over all $\tau \in S_r$, this is the same as summing over $\sigma^{-1}\tau \in S_r$ (note that $\tau \mapsto \sigma^{-1}\tau$ is a bijection), so replacing $\tau$ with $\sigma^{-1}\tau$ you get the same sum.

Comment: @user37864 So the bijection comes from the fact that $\sigma,\tau \in S_r$. Thank you very much, I understand now the proof. It was much more tricky than I was thinking.